# make first line colorful in ListView from array.xml

Tags: android

I got an app that include listview and i want the first line of the listview in blue.
i did the listview from an array xml here is the code&XML:
JAVA:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
 ListView list;
 ArrayAdapter<String> adaptr;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adaptr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
            , getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_view));
    list.setAdapter(adaptr);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    list.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

}  

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(this, R.style.PauseDialog);
    dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.dialog1);
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    dialog1.setTitle(R.string.Title);

    if(position == 1) {
        text.setText("First Dialog");
        dialog1.show();
        }
    if(position == 2) {
        text.setText("Second Dialog");
        dialog1.show();
        return;
        }   
    if(position == 3) {
        text.setText("Third Dialog");
        dialog1.show();
        return;
        }
}
```

here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="list_view"> 
      <item>All Rights Saved to XXX</item>
      <item>Line 1</item>
      <item>Line 2</item>   
      <item>Line 3</item>
    </array> 
</resources>
```

i want the first item("All Rghits....") will be in blue(color)
(and the other will be regular(black))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could programmatically add a HeaderView using [listView.addheaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) .
You can change the View color to blue

Comment: Can you please give me example?
I can't find nothing working on the internet

Comment: Check this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#miscellaneous_headerfooter

Comment: what i need to write in the header layout?textview?

Comment: Whatever your blue colored layout should look like. You need to change its color

Answer (score 0):

write your own `Adapter` that extends `ArrayAdapter`. then you can return whatever `View` you need in your `getView()` method implementation.